# Is there a way to specify the view to use in mvc4 route.config for each action methods inside a contoller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view(Layout.cshtml) where i display three dropdowns and a table ,I do all the action inside the Index() method of Homecontroller .I want to do some processing of data inside another method in the Homecontroller and display the results in the same view (Layout.cshtml) , I tried to return View(mydata) inside the second method but cannot display the same page ,the only way iam able to do it is store in tempdata and do RedirectToAction("Index") and get values from tempdata inside it.

Is there a way in the route.config to map to the same view for the second method as well.My route.config looks like this

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Iam new to MVC and don't know how to use the route.config file

Comment: Can you place the code for the two methods i.e. Index, "another method"?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to change the routing. the typical look of layout.cshtml is a page with some html tags and a @RenderBody. but you can add also some @Html.Action() to the layout that will fit your needs. for example Add the @Html.Action("DoMore" , "Home" , new {area=""}) to the layout and it will execute the DoMore action of Home controller on each render of layout.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      @Html.Action("DoMore" , "Home" , new {area=""})
    </div>
    <div>
       @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply actually I have a actionlink inside the cshtml file that calls this method inside the controller when the user selects a value from dropdownlist ,but after I process inside the action method I need to display this updated data back in the view ,its not happening until I store this updated data in tempdata and pass it into Index method ,if I try to call the view from this second action method directly I get the error "the view cannot be called directly as it calls a renderbody method"

Comment: I call the view directly with the data like this in the second action method in controller return View ("_Layout", data);

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do and it's doesn't seem right to pass the layout like this, anyway I just assume that you want to change a part of your page based on what user chooses from dropdown, I think the best approach is using the mixture of "change" and "ajax" methods of jquery. have a look : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  http://api.jquery.com/change/